# Magento 2.3: system.xml and config.xml: Default values not showing up in the admin

Tags: magento2, module, magento2.3, configuration, system.xml

I'm developing a module for Magento 2.3 and can't get default config values to show up in the admin. To the best of my knowledge, I've followed all the documentation I can find. It's kind of driving me crazy :)

A link to my full project can be found here: https://github.com/crankycyclops/DiscountCodeUrl

And here are the contents of the two relevant files:

etc/adminhtml/system.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">

    <system>

        <section id="promo">

            <group id="discounturl" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">

                <label>Discount URL Settings</label>

                <field id="enabled" translate="label comment" type="select" sortOrder="60" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enabled</label>
                    <comment>If the discount URL module is enabled, you'll be able to apply discount codes automatically via URL. Disable this if you have other modules running that implement similar behavior or that might conflict.</comment>
                    <validate>required-entry</validate>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>

                <field id="url_param" translate="label comment" type="text" sortOrder="60" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>URL Parameter</label>
                    <comment>This is the GET parameter that will contain a coupon code in the URL. For example, if this value is "coupon", then https://store.url?coupon=CODE will set the coupon code to "CODE." If this value isn't set, we'll use the hardcoded default specified by Helper\Cookie::DEFAULT_URL_PARAMETER.</comment>
                </field>

                <field id="cookie_lifetime" translate="label comment" type="text" sortOrder="60" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Cookie Lifetime</label>
                    <comment>When a coupon code comes in through a URL, we set it in a cookie so that we can remember it for the entire session. This value determines how long that cookie should stay set before it expires (in seconds.) Value must be 0 or greater (0 means the cookie will remain alive until the browser window or tab remains open.) If this value isn't set, we'll use the hardcoded default specified by Helper\Cookie::COOKIE_LIFETIME.</comment>
                    <validate>validate-zero-or-greater</validate>
                </field>

            </group>

        </section>

    </system>

</config>
```

etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">

    <default>

        <promo>

            <discounturl>

                <enabled>0</enabled>
                <url_param>coupon</url_param>
                <cookie_lifetime>0</cookie_lifetime>

            </discounturl>

        </promo>

    </default>

</config>
```

Comment: I can see your config value in admin!

Comment: That's weird. I can't, even after flushing my cache.

Comment: I download your module from git and and it showing correctly!

Comment: which mode you are using ?

Comment: @Pawan development mode. I'm on 2.3.3.

Comment: check `log/exception` if  there any

Comment: In the exception log, I only see unrelated exceptions that were thrown by the observers when I was testing and debugging. I guess it's not that big of a deal, as long as I know the code will work correctly for others. I'll be changing the default values when I use this myself anyway.

Comment: OK......great:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is working for others and there's just something strange going on with my own instance of Magento.

Comment: just repliated for me when i just installed fresh version  magetno 2.3.3  uing composer but after flushing cache after some time, issue fixed automatically, may be becuase of  low server resources,

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for letting me know.